# Getting the SecurityToken for a Currently Logged In User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity

Is it possible to get the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken object from HttpContext.Current.User?

Here is about as far as I was able to get:

```
IPrincipal userPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User; 
WindowsIdentity userIdentity = userPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity; 
IntPtr token = userIdentity.Token;
```

But, I am unable to get the SecurityToken due to the following error:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion
```

**Update:**

It looks like the way to get the SecurityToken is by using BootstrapContext:

```
BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
var token = bootstrapContext.SecurityToken;
```

And, in the web.config:

```
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

Comment: if you are wanting to get the current user why not do the following 
`var currentUser = Convert.ToString(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name).Split('\\');`

Comment: Why are you trying to assign it to an `IntPtr`?

Comment: My coworkers created a REST API that according to them takes the token as an argument.

Comment: @RonBeyer That is just the code snippet that I found.

Comment: @AllanHorwitz It doesn't make sense, have you tried instead: `var token = userIdentity.Token;`?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes. It automatically types it as IntPtr.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- the docs all say `IntPtr` what type would you recommend?

Comment: @DavidTansey Yes, thats right, I mistook it to be that the error he was getting (`'System.IntPtr' to 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken'`) was from the `IntPtr token = userIdentity.Token;` line.